# NestJS Swagger - How to declare multiselect enum field?

Tags: node.js, swagger, nestjs

I'm using @nestjs/swagger module in my application. I would like to declare multiselect enum field for one of my query parameters. I've read in the documentation that I can achieve this by combining `enum`and `isArray` properties. So I did something like:

```
class QueryParams {
  @ApiModelProperty({
    enum: ['test_status_1', 'test_status_2'],
    isArray: true
  })
  status: string[]
}
```

I'm using this class to validate query. Unfortunately it's not working. So I decided to use `@ApiImplicitQuery` in my controller like this:

```
@ApiImplicitQuery({
  name: 'status',
  enum: ['test_status_1', 'test_status_2'],
  isArray: true,
  collectionFormat: 'csv'
})
```

This allowed my to declare multiselect enum, but there is a problem with the way those parameters are being added to the url. If I select multiple values I get:

```
?status=test_status_1&status=test_status2
```

I would like them to be send using `csv` format as I specified above. Right now it's using `multi` format. Is there a way to achieve this? I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Regarding the problem with the multi-select, I experienced the same problem. As I could not find an existing issue, I created issue 237 with the nestjs/swagger project. Check https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/237 for details.

Comment: I have also created another issue for your URL problem, the issue number is 238 and can be found at https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/238.

Comment: did you find a solution? I am trying to use multiselect enum field

Comment: I presume this is still unresolved? :/

Answer (score 4):

I did something like this:

```js
@ApiProperty({
        isArray: true,
        required: false,
        enum: TestCaseFiltersStatuses,
    })
    @IsOptional()
    @IsEnum(TestCaseFiltersStatuses, {each: true})
    @IsArray()
    @Transform((value) => {
        if (typeof value == 'string') {
            return value.split(',')
        }
        return value;
    })
    statuses?: TestCaseFiltersStatuses[];

.
.
.
async testCaseList(@Query(new ValidationPipe({transform: true})) query: TestCaseFiltersModel) {
...
}
```

that way this supports both `?params=1&params=2` and `?params=1,2`